# Python and Pandas: Get counts of people in a column, by a date

Tags: python, pandas

I basically have a data set of 3 columns.

```
Restaurant | Customer | Date
```

There are multiple restaurants, customers and dates.
Using python/pandas I'm trying to find the counts of each customer who has at least 3 visits or more to a single restaurant, and separately, 3 or more visits to ANY of the restaurants. (example: 1 person visited 3 different restaurants)

I would also like to see the count of unique devices, who have visited a restaurant 3 or more times.

So far I have:

```
df.groupby(['Restaurant','name'])['date'].value_counts()
```

which gives me the count of times visited by date, but I want the actual number of dates visited. (Unique dates)

Thanks for any help! I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Berry py's setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'restaurant':['Freddys', 'Freddys', 'Jumpin Java', 'Freddys', 'Jumpin Java', 'Caffe Low', 'Kitchen 2'], 
                    'customer': ['John', 'John', 'Paula', 'John', 'Justin', 'Paula', 'Paula'], 
                    'date':['1-1-17', '1-2-17', '1-3-17', '1-4-17', '1-5-17', '1-6-17', '1-7-17']})

df_out = df.groupby('customer').agg({'customer':'size','restaurant':'nunique'}).rename(columns={'customer':'Num_Visits','restaurant':"Num_Restaurants"})

df_out.query('Num_Visits >= 3')
```

Output:

```
         Num_Visits  Num_Restaurants
customer                             
John               3                1
Paula              3                3
```

Comment: This got me on the right track! Thanks @berrypy and ScottBoston, the following worked for my situation `df_out = df.groupby('customer').agg({'customer':'size','date':'nunique'}).rename(columns={'customer':'Num_Visits','date':"Num_Dates"})`

Answer (score 0):

Set up data scenario that matches your explanation.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'restaurant':['Freddys', 'Freddys', 'Jumpin Java', 'Freddys', 'Jumpin Java', 'Caffe Low', 'Kitchen 2'], 
                    'customer': ['John', 'John', 'Paula', 'John', 'Justin', 'Paula', 'Paula'], 
                    'date':['1-1-17', '1-2-17', '1-3-17', '1-4-17', '1-5-17', '1-6-17', '1-7-17']})

  customer    date   restaurant
0     John  1-1-17      Freddys
1     John  1-2-17      Freddys
2    Paula  1-3-17  Jumpin Java
3     John  1-4-17      Freddys
4   Justin  1-5-17  Jumpin Java
5    Paula  1-6-17    Caffe Low
6    Paula  1-7-17    Kitchen 2
```

Create function to return the conditions that you specify.

```
def get_eating_pattern(df):
    for name in df.customer.unique():
        three_visits = 0
        total_visits = 0
        unique_rests = 0

        three_visits = df.loc[df['customer'] == name]['restaurant'].value_counts()[0]
        if '3' in str(three_visits):
            print(name, 'went to the same restaurant 3 times.')

        total_visits = df.loc[df['customer'] == name]['restaurant'].value_counts().sum()
        unique_rests = df.loc[df['customer'] == name]['restaurant'].nunique()

        if total_visits == 3 & unique_rests == 3:
            print(name, 'went to 3 different restaurants.')
```

Test function to make sure it matches what we expected based on the content of `df`.

```
>>> get_eating_pattern(df=df)
John went to the same restaurant 3 times.
Paula went to 3 different restaurants.
```